# jenkins slave in mesos not start

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mesos, mesosphere

I am using:

- jenkins 1.595
- mesos jenkins plugin 0.5.0
- mesos 0.21.0

I have configured Cloud Mesos in jenkins. Jenkins framework is already registerd with description in mesos frameworks view like this:

Id: 5050-2830-29614

Host: My-PC

User: Jenkins

Name: Jenkins Scheduler

Active Tasks: 0

CPU: 1.7

Mem: 2.5 Gb

Max Share: 37442%

Registered: 33 minutes ago

Re-Registered: -

But Jenkins not show online slave and get this output
Starting mesos slave mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /computer/mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd/logText/progressiveHtml. Reason:

    Not Found
```

and this log

```
INFO: Enqueuing jenkins slave request
Jan 13, 2015 10:18:57 AM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
Jan 13, 2015 10:20:12 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosRetentionStrategy check
INFO: Disconnecting offline computer mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd
Jan 13, 2015 10:20:12 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosSlave terminate
INFO: Terminating slave mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd
Jan 13, 2015 10:20:12 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler terminateJenkinsSlave
INFO: Terminating jenkins slave mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd
Jan 13, 2015 10:20:12 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler terminateJenkinsSlave
INFO: Removing enqueued mesos task mesos-jenkins-d4dd533e-bed4-44bc-b0d9-8fc5474710bd
Jan 13, 2015 10:21:24 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
```

the log in mesos is this:

```
I0113 10:07:13.690115  2851 master.cpp:1434] Framework 20150105-100316-1275074476-5050-2830-29614 (Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612 already registered, resending acknowledgement
I0113 10:07:14.690235  2854 master.cpp:1383] Received registration request for framework 'Jenkins Scheduler' at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612
I0113 10:07:14.690510  2854 master.cpp:1434] Framework 20150105-100316-1275074476-5050-2830-29614 (Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612 already registered, resending acknowledgement
I0113 10:07:15.690466  2854 master.cpp:1383] Received registration request for framework 'Jenkins Scheduler' at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612
I0113 10:07:15.690723  2854 master.cpp:1434] Framework 20150105-100316-1275074476-5050-2830-29614 (Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612 already registered, resending acknowledgement
I0113 10:07:16.691149  2852 master.cpp:1383] Received registration request for framework 'Jenkins Scheduler' at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612
I0113 10:07:16.691689  2852 master.cpp:1434] Framework 20150105-100316-1275074476-5050-2830-29614 (Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612 already registered, resending acknowledgement
I0113 10:07:17.691560  2853 master.cpp:1383] Received registration request for framework 'Jenkins Scheduler' at scheduler-83e56c80-e586-4564-88cb-e0fd541ad845@172.23.0.76:58612
```

and so on...

also mesos show
**Offered   1.7     2.5 GB**  (the same resources of framework registered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the environment variable LIBPROCESS_IP="IP of the jenkins host". See [mesos/chronos#193](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/193)